# Is it possible to get non-inherited field or method from inherited object in collection?

Tags: java, inheritance

It's a simple example of my code, Im stuck, how to get non-inherited field `private int age;` from Parent class.

Another words, how to avoid of creating unwanted fields in Parent class?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setName("Bob");
        child.setAge(10);

        List<Parent> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(parent);
        list.add(child);

        System.out.println(list.get(1).getName());
        System.out.println(list.get(1).getAge()); // here is crushed
    }
}

class Parent {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your List as Parent this is why you only have access to the Parents attributes/methods.

You can run a simple type check and cast the object to Child afterwards.

```
Parent p = list.get(1)
if(p instanceof Child){
    System.out.println((Child)p.getAge());
}
```